# How does map() and imap() work in gevent.pool.Pool?

Tags: python, gevent

I wrote a script to learn about `gevent.pool.Pool`, but I have seen a strange phonemenon.

In my code, I have three different code segments, named *version 1*, *version 2* and *version 3*.

- When commenting out *version 2* and *version 3*, namely just using the **imap()** method in *version 1*, then there's nothing to happen.
- When commenting out *version 1* and *version 3*, namely just using the **map()** method in *version 2*, then I find that the first **map()** method creates two greenlets and then the two greenlets execute. After those two greenles are done, then the second **map()** method does the same thing.
- When commenting out *version 1* and *version 2*, namely first using the **imap()** method and then using **map()** method in *version 3*, I find that until the **map()** method has been executed, then the five greenlets are created and executed.

So I have two questions:

- Why does **map()** method triggers the execution while **imap()** not?
- Why does the `Pool` instance have a non-zero length after **map()** triggers the execution?

I have read the source code of **pool.py** in gevent-1.0, but I don't understand how the source code adds greenlets to the variable **self.greenlets** and the difference between **map()** and **imap()**. In my option, **imap()** just returns an iterable objects and **map()** returns a list of greenlets generated by **imap()**.

Here is the source code of **map()** and **imap()** in **pool.py** of gevent:

```
def map(self, func, iterable):
    return list(self.imap(func, iterable))

def imap(self, func, iterable):
    """An equivalent of itertools.imap()"""
    return IMap.spawn(func, iterable, spawn=self.spawn)
```

Here is my test code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
#coding: utf-8

import gevent
from gevent.pool import Pool
from gevent.coros import BoundedSemaphore


class TestSemaphore(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.sem = BoundedSemaphore(1)
        self.pool = Pool()

    def run(self):
        # version 1 
        self.pool.imap(self._worker, xrange(0, 2))
        self.pool.imap(self._worker, xrange(3, 6))
        # end of version 1

        # version 2
        # self.pool.map(self._worker, xrange(0, 2))
        # self.pool.map(self._worker, xrange(3, 6))
        # end of version 2

        # version 3
        # self.pool.imap(self._worker, xrange(0, 2))
        # self.pool.map(self._worker, xrange(3, 6))
        # end of version 3

    def _worker(self, pid):
        with self.sem:
            print('worker %d acquired semaphore, length of pool is %d' % (pid, len(self.pool)))
            gevent.sleep(0)
        print('worker %d released semaphore, length of pool is %d' % (pid, len(self.pool))) 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test = TestSemaphore()
    test.run()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key thing to note is that `imap` is *lazy* - it does not do any work until you actually consume the resulting iterator:

```
>>> map(lamda x: x, xrange(0, 2))
[0, 1]

>>> from itertools import imap
>>> imap(lamda x: x, xrange(0, 2))
<generator object at 0xsome-address>

# Consume the resulting iterator
>>> list(imap(lamda x: x, xrange(0, 2)))
[0, 1]
```

`imap` in `multiprocessing` and `gevent` adheres to the same rules.

Comment: The **Pool** instance is not a greenlet and after it adds the greenlets to itself, how does the **Pool** instance triggers those greenlets to execute? Here is [another test script](https://gist.github.com/flyer103/7823145) and the greenlets don't execute.

Comment: @flyer: I don't see how your test script is related to the usage of `gevent.pool.Pool.imap()` that is modeled after `multiprocessing.Pool.imap` (a simplistic interface modeled after builtin `map()`)

Comment: Sorry for my poor expression. The another test script just shows that Pool instance is not a greenlet and the greenlets in it don't execute. By this, I want to know why the **map()** triggers the greenlets in a Pool instance to execute.

Comment: @flyer - `IMap` however *is* a greenlet and `map` calls `imap` and then explicitly runs it (using `list`).  Under the hood, `IMap` uses a `Queue` and pulls entries off the queue using `get`.

Comment: @flyer - in your test, the greenlets don't execute because you never `join` them - see [my updated gist](https://gist.github.com/svieira/7827139)

Comment: Thank you very much! Your two last comments solved my two questions. After reading the source code again with your help of explanation, I know why the Pool instance has the behavior. Thanks again. :D